# Autocomplete list poorly formatted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup autocomplete in a rails app but every time I type a letter in the autocomplete field the entire list of options show up. How can I get it to show max 5 items in a line by line dropdown box format. I would also like to get only the transaction name so instead of

```
Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JULYOSW CA
```

I get

```
UBER
```

Any regex or other options I can use on a list as diverse as this?

Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JULYOSW CA ,Transfer From PAYMENT/TRANSFER BA,Debit Card Purchase /#FANTASY SAIL & SIGN MIAMI FL ,Fandango,Debit Card Purchase /:p #ANGEL'S RESTAURANT CHICAGO IL ,Debit PIN Purchase #JEWEL BENSENVILLE ILUS,Debit Card Purchase /:p #EXPRESS#MIAMI BEACH FL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #TGI FRIDAYS #MIAMI FL ,Domino's,Wendy's,Deposit :a #Citibank ATM S. ARCHER AVE,CHICAGO,IL,Debit Card Purchase /:p #PLAYSTATION NETWORK CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JULHVRDCA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JULLIORT CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #SLEEPING BEAR DNL-DC E EMPIRE MI ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #MNN/GILBERT CAFE#QPS MIAMI FL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #SHOWPLACE ICON THEATRE CHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #DUNKIN #QMIAMI FL ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #DD/BR #QCHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #DD/BR #QCHICAGO IL ,Cracker Barrel,Debit PIN Purchase BURLNGTON STORESCHICAGO ILUS,Meijer,Costco,Debit PIN Purchase SAWYER'S TRAVEL SAWYER MIUS,Debit PIN Purchase POWER MARKET ELMHURST ILUS,Debit PIN Purchase #JEWEL CHICAGO ILUS,DIRECTV,Debit Card Purchase /:a #OLD TOWN TROLLEY TOU KEY WEST FL ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #AMERICANCHICAGO IL ,Amazon,Debit Card Purchase /:a #UBER US JUNUCFZ CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #CARNIVAL- THE FUN SHOP MIAMI FL ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #PLAYSTATION NETWORK CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #UBER US JUNEZOFCA ,Six Flags,Debit Card Purchase /:a #DUNKIN #QCHICAGO IL ,CVS,Debit Card Purchase /:a #SP *KEN TONE'S DRIVE-I CHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JUNBMLO CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UI HOSP FCID/PCAC CHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER US JUNRNBI CA ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UIC PARKING WSPS CHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #Tire Tracks Elmhurst IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #EL FARO CHICAGO IL ,Walgreens,Bill Payment HOMEQ SERVICING CORPORATION MOBL,ACH Electronic Credit BOARD OF ED CITY DIR DEP,Home Depot,Shell,Debit Card Purchase /:p #ASTI ITALIAN DELI BENSENVILLE IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #PARK CHICAGO MOBILE IL ,Comcast,Debit Card Purchase /:p #HAWKEYES BAR GRILL I CHICAGO IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #XSPORT SOUTH LOOP-CKFR IL ,Debit Card Purchase /:p #UBER JUNUS ETWCA ,Bill Payment TARGET NATIONAL BANK MOBL,Debit Card Purchase /:p #CROCS INC CROCS.COM CO ,Debit Card Purchase /:a #BANFIELD WELLNESS PLAN OR ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails-jquery-autocomplete shows entire array instead of selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308260/rails-jquery-autocomplete-shows-entire-array-instead-of-selections)

Comment: You should not post _an update to this question_ as another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some great gems to handle this. Have a look at `rails-query-autocomplete`.

If you want to limit your autocomplete search result, you can do this directly on a model via `Model.limit(5)`. Or you can do this in the controller by returning a subset of an array containing possible results. If you're doing the array method, you'll want to consider how to return your most-relevant results.

Comment: I am using that gem but the autocomplete still shows my entire array. not just items that match what the user is typing

Comment: Are you using a named scope to fetch the autocomplete results?

Comment: No, here is an update to this question with better details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308260/rails-jquery-autocomplete-shows-entire-array-instead-of-selections